# unable to recognize "filebeat-kubernetes.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat, daemonset

I'm trying to run FileBeat on minikube following this doc with k8s 1.16
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.4/running-on-kubernetes.html

I downloaded the manifest file as instructed

```
curl -L -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/7.4/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml
```

Contents of the yaml file below

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"

    # To enable hints based autodiscover, remove `filebeat.inputs` configuration and uncomment this:
    #filebeat.autodiscover:
    #  providers:
    #    - type: kubernetes
    #      host: ${NODE_NAME}
    #      hints.enabled: true
    #      hints.default_config:
    #        type: container
    #        paths:
    #          - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log

    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:
      - add_host_metadata:

    cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.4.0
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: changeme
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          # If using Red Hat OpenShift uncomment this:
          #privileged: true
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
      - name: data
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
---
```

When I try the deploy step,

```
kubectl create -f filebeat-kubernetes.yaml
```

I get the output + error:

configmap/filebeat-config created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/filebeat created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/filebeat created
serviceaccount/filebeat created
error: unable to recognize "filebeat-kubernetes.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Comment: your yalm has format issue, double check it.

Comment: Without knowing what version of kubernetes you're on it's hard to answer specifically, but be aware that [`DaemonSet` now lives in `apps/v1`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#daemonset-v1-apps). You may want to increase the verbosity of your `kubectl create` as it will sometimes give those resource errors if you are not authenticated, too

Comment: Updated the post, using version 1.16. Do you mean for the DaemonSet, I should change the apiVersion to apps/v1? That gives me this error, 

`error validating "filebeat-kubernetes.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(DaemonSet.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false.`

Comment: [The documentation for `DaemonSetSpec`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#daemonsetspec-v1-apps) indicates which fields are required, and the structure of them. Perhaps you'd be happier with [the Elastic helm charts](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/7.4.0/filebeat#installing), since it correctly [provides the `selector:` field](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/7.4.0/filebeat/templates/daemonset.yaml#L15-L18)?

Answer (score 12):

As we can see [there](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/)

> **DaemonSet**, Deployment, StatefulSet, and ReplicaSet resources will no longer be served from extensions/v1beta1, apps/v1beta1, or apps/v1beta2 by default in v1.16. Migrate to the apps/v1 API

You need to change [apiVersion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-versioning)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 -> apiVersion: apps/v1
```

Then there is another error

`missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetSpec;`

So we have to add selector field

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
```

Edited DaemonSet yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.4.0
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: changeme
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          # If using Red Hat OpenShift uncomment this:
          #privileged: true
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
      - name: data
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Let me know if that help you.